# Cannot connect to Solace Cloud

Tags: solace

I am following the solace tutorial for Publish/Subscribe (link: https://dev.solace.com/samples/solace-samples-java/publish-subscribe/). Therefore, there shouldn't be anything "wrong" with the code.

I am trying to get my TopicSubscriber to connect to the cloud. After building my jar I run the following command:

`java -cp target/SOM_Enrichment-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar TopicSubscriber <host:port> <client-username@message-vpn> <password>`

(with the appropriate fields filled in)

I get the following error:

```
TopicSubscriber initializing...
Jul 12, 2018 2:27:56 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel call
INFO: Connecting to host 'blocked out' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 2, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
Jul 12, 2018 2:28:17 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel call
INFO: Connection attempt failed to host 'blocked out' ConnectException com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException: ('blocked out') - Error communicating with the router. cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information ((Client name: 'blocked out'   Local port: -1   Remote addr: 'blocked out') - )
Jul 12, 2018 2:28:20 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel close
INFO: Channel Closed (smfclient 2)
Exception in thread "main" com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException" (Client name: 'blocked out'   Local port: -1   Remote addr: 'blocked out') - Error communicating with the router.
```

Below is the TopicSubscriber.java file:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.BytesXMLMessage;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPException;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPFactory;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPProperties;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPSession;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.TextMessage;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.Topic;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.XMLMessageConsumer;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.XMLMessageListener;

public class TopicSubscriber {

    public static void main(String... args) throws JCSMPException {

        // Check command line arguments
    if (args.length != 3 || args[1].split("@").length != 2) {
        System.out.println("Usage: TopicSubscriber <host:port> <client-username@message-vpn> <client-password>");
        System.out.println();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    if (args[1].split("@")[0].isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No client-username entered");
        System.out.println();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    if (args[1].split("@")[1].isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No message-vpn entered");
        System.out.println();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("TopicSubscriber initializing...");
    final JCSMPProperties properties = new JCSMPProperties();
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.HOST, args[0]);     // host:port
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.USERNAME, args[1].split("@")[0]); // client-username
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.PASSWORD, args[2]); // client-password
    properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.VPN_NAME, args[1].split("@")[1]); // message-vpn
    final Topic topic = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createTopic("tutorial/topic");
    final JCSMPSession session = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties);

    session.connect();

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); // used for
    // synchronizing b/w threads
    /** Anonymous inner-class for MessageListener
     *  This demonstrates the async threaded message callback */
    final XMLMessageConsumer cons = session.getMessageConsumer(new XMLMessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(BytesXMLMessage msg) {
            if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
                System.out.printf("TextMessage received: '%s'%n",
                        ((TextMessage) msg).getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Message received.");
            }
            System.out.printf("Message Dump:%n%s%n", msg.dump());
            latch.countDown();  // unblock main thread
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(JCSMPException e) {
            System.out.printf("Consumer received exception: %s%n", e);
            latch.countDown();  // unblock main thread
        }
    });
    session.addSubscription(topic);
    System.out.println("Connected. Awaiting message...");
    cons.start();
    // Consume-only session is now hooked up and running!

    try {
        latch.await(); // block here until message received, and latch will flip
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("I was awoken while waiting");
    }
    // Close consumer
    cons.close();
    System.out.println("Exiting.");
    session.closeSession();
 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out`

The log entry indicates that network connectivity to the specified DNS name/IP address cannot be established.

Next step includes:

1. Verifying that you are able to resolve the DNS name to an IP
   address.
2. Verifying that the correct DNS name/IP address/Port is in use - You need the "SMF Host" in the Solace Cloud Connection Details.
3. Verifying that the IP address/Port is not blocked by an intermediate network device.

Comment: hmm, where I just checked my solace service and the status is running. i'm not too sure how to perform the steps you listed.. a bit new to all this haha

Comment: As a first step there's always the command line utility ping: "ping <SMF Host>" To verify connectivity to the specific tcp port, you can try telnet: "telnet <SMF Host> <Port>" These commands should work out of the box on most Unix-like operating systems including Macs, and in Cygwin on Windows.